# Model responsibilities in MVVM

Tags: mvvm, model

Is Model only Entity Data Model class of my database? Model as simple place where i have my data? Or I can input in Model something more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model in MVVM is supposed to be the place for data-centric logic and the data, yes. It can be just the Entity Data Model, or you can add some more logic--that's up to you. The primary point is to seperate any presentation-specific logic from the model and put that in the viewmodel.

Hope that's clear enough

Comment: About data-centric logic You just mean the methods which is automate created by Visual Studio when we create EDM? Or something more logic?

Comment: I don't think in your case you'll need to put any more in there, nope.

Just stick with generated models by EDM -- and use those directly from the ViewModel

Answer (score 1):

You can do whatever you like...

Typically, though, the "model" in MVVM is considered to be an "external" class (e.g. a generated class from LINQ-to-Entities, say) and so it usually doesn't have much logic.

Answer (score 1):

The model is the core domain logic you are dealing with.  It is *everything* not directly related to a UI view.

An easy way to think of it is the View and ViewModel combined represent what would be a "typical" UI layer without good separation.  In MVVM, you split the logical aspects (the ViewModel) from the display logic (the View).